# Where can I learn about mathematical notation?

Tags: notation

I often see mathematical notation on Wikipedia articles (e.g. [Finding the matrix of a transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Finding_the_matrix_of_a_transformation)). Where is a good resource for learning what the different symbols mean?

Comment: the question already seems to have been discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720993/how-to-learn-mathematical-notation

Comment: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check out the following [wikipedia web page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols) It is a list of mathematical symbols and the associated $\LaTeX$ codes.

However I feel that in order for one to be truly accustomed to notation, you should read mathematics and try and figure out the notation as you go along. Gradually after a while you will build up a knowledge base of what certain symbols mean/ which conventions are employed.

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like an inexpensive, handy reference to mathematical notation please check out my book available at Amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Notation-Guide-Engineers-Scientists/dp/1466230525/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1355100927&sr=1-1&keywords=mathematical+notation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466230525)

If you find it useful, please give it a thumbs up on its Facebook page.

Comment: From the Amazon blurb: "Our goal is to cover mathematical notation commonly used by engineers and scientists".  Any chance you are working on a follow up edition to "cover mathematical notation commonly used by mathematicians"?

Answer (score 4):

From your link, it looks like the stuff that is troubling you is related to vectors and linear algebra type notation.  The best way to learn this stuff is from a general calculus book (up through multi-variable calculus).  It really depends more on what you're getting stuck on.  I agree with Benjamin, the best way to learn is by reading math and DOING math, because it's important to intuitively understand the symbols and what they represent. A good place to start might be [the Stewart book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534359493), which covers Calc I, II and III.

After that, you'll want to start learning the algebraic notation which mostly comes from set theory and logic, so a book like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470551380) might help (this is just sort of a shot in the dark, I don't personally know anything about this book, but something like this).  Much of this stuff you can probably find in books at a book store like Borders.  Also, just Google things like "standard math notation, matrices" or something.  There's lots of info online.